# Java periodic values cache architecture

Tags: java, algorithm, caching, architecture

The task is to implement cache for periodic values. To be more particular - these are some records related to the bank account. Each record has an date and some position within a day. Thus, each record is comparable by those properties. Cache must contain List of records related to the queried period. Also cached values can be merged when query for a bigger period was performed.

Let's consider couple examples. History for some particular account has 10 records (date format is MM/dd/yyyy:

```
01/01/2012 
02/01/2012 
03/01/2012 
04/01/2012 
05/01/2012 
06/01/2012 
07/01/2012 
08/01/2012 
09/01/2012 
10/01/2012
```

*Example 1*

First query was for period 02/15/2012 - 03/15/2012.

Query result will be a single record:

```
03/01/2012
```

Cache should contain record: key "02/15/2012 - 03/15/2012", value ["03/01/2012"]

All queries for that period or sub-period (i.e. 02/16/2012-03/15/2012) should return "03/01/2012" right from cache.

Second query performed was for period 01/15/2012 - 02/16/2012.

Query result will be two records:

```
02/01/2012
03/01/2012
```

There are following things to mention:

1) Query to the underlying data storage should be performed only for period 01/15/2012 - 02/14/2012. This is because cache already contains all entries from 02/15/2012.

2) Single cache entry's bounds will be updated along with the number of records it stores.

As a result cache then should contain a single record: key "01/15/2012 - 03/15/2012", value ["02/01/2012", "03/01/2012"].

Then any query for a sub period should find a cache entry by key and then select desired records from cache.

*Example 2*

Current cache state is:

```
Entry 1: "01/15/2012 - 03/15/2012" => ["02/01/2012", "03/01/2012"]
Entry 2: "04/15/2012 - 05/15/2012" => ["05/01/2012"]
Entry 3: "07/02/2012 - 09/02/2012" => ["08/01/2012", "09/01/2012"]
```

The query is performed for period 01/01/2012 - 10/01/2012. Result contains all history of records:

```
01/01/2012 
02/01/2012 
03/01/2012 
04/01/2012 
05/01/2012 
06/01/2012 
07/01/2012 
08/01/2012 
09/01/2012 
10/01/2012
```

Cache should contain a single entry: key "01/01/2012", value ["01/01/2012", "02/01/2012", "03/01/2012", "04/01/2012", "05/01/2012", "06/01/2012", "07/01/2012", "08/01/2012", "09/01/2012", "10/01/2012"].

---

I'm challenging this task for a week and can't find any beautyful simple algorithm to work with such cache.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think an [Interval Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) might fit your needs - [here is a Java implementation](https://github.com/KevinStern/software-and-algorithms/blob/master/src/main/java/blogspot/software_and_algorithms/stern_library/data_structure/DynamicIntervalTree.java). An interval tree stores intervals and can be queried by intervals (e.g. you can store [1, 5], [2, 7], [6, 10], query it on [3, 5], and it returns [1, 5], [2, 7] i.e. all intervals that overlap with the query). You're storing points instead of intervals, but just store your points as sufficiently small non-overlapping intervals and you're good to go.

Because this is intended to be a cache, you may want to store your keys and values within [SoftReferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html) - this will allow the garbage collector to free them if you would otherwise encounter an `OutOfMemoryError`.